# Use make with more

Tags: make

When I try to filter make with more it does not work:

```
make | more
```

Not exactly sure why that it is. How do I paginate make's output?

By "does not work" I mean it does not work at all. It is as though the more filter was never added. The output from make just scrolls off the screen.

Comment: @Kusalananda The output just scrolls off the screen and is not paginated. In other words the output is the same as if | more had not been added.

Answer (score 3):

You are not sending the error stream of `make` through `more`, so no diagnostic messages would be paginated by `more`.

To send both standard output and standard error through `more`, use

```
make 2>&1 | more
```

Note that if `make` produces *lots* of output, and if you don't follow it in `more`, then the output of `make` would eventually be blocked, causing the `make` process to pause until such time that you have scrolled down to the most recent part of the output in `more`.

It may be better to do

```
make >make.log 2>&1
```

followed by

```
tail -f make.log
```

This would start `make` with all output sent to a new file called `make.log`.  The `tail` command is then used to follow the output (you could obviously use `more make.log` instead).